# How to write group join query in Entity Framewok Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

When I write the linq query like this, I get the error message

> "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .GroupJoin(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: d => d.Id,
> innerKeySelector: dc => dc.DeviceId,
> resultSelector: (d, dc) => new {
> deviceName = d.Name,
> cams = dc
> })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

How should I edit the code?

```
var query = context.Devices
                   .GroupJoin(context.DeviceControls,
                              d => d.Id,
                              dc => dc.DeviceId,
                              (d, dc) => new
                                         {
                                             deviceName = d.Name,
                                             Cams = dc,
                                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: Don't join, use a navigation property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF core with .net core 3.1 will not let you do group by unless you do it client side.  You need to call var query = context.Devices.ToList() and then do your group call on the query variable.  Another option, if possible, is upgrading to .net 6.  I think then you can do a server side group by.

Comment: Thank you for answer .my problem was resolved when i did query = context.Devices.ToList()